# Como enviar a formatação do CKEditor para o BD?

Tags: php, mysql, ckeditor, echo, bbcode

A minha dúvida é a seguinte, configurei o `CKEditor` dentro de um `textarea`, onde tudo que eu digitar envia para o `banco de dados` que ao mesmo tempo alimenta outra página, funcionando no estilo `sistema de noticias`.

Porém na página que deve abrir o contéudo digitado e com a formatação abre com código fonte sem formatação

**EXEMPLO:**

`T<strong>ES</strong>TE`

**CÓDIGO DO SISTEMA ONDE FICA O CKEDITOR:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<textarea class="ckeditor" name="descricaodoevento" id="descricaodoevento"><? echo("$prof[descricaodoevento]");?></textarea>
```

**BANCO DE DADOS:**

[image: banco de dados]

*Não sei se tenho que alterar o Tipo e Agrupamento (Collation).*

**PÁGINA ONDE RECEBE O SISTEMA (tipo sistema de nóticias):**

```
<div class="bar1"> <h2>Descrição</h2></div>
<? echo("$usr[descricaodoevento]");?>
```

***Imagem de Error***

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

***Porque será que isso ta acontecendo?***

Answer (score 1):

Use **[htmlspecialchars_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php)**:

```
<?php echo(htmlspecialchars_decode($usr['descricaodoevento']));?>
```

*Referências:*

- [htmlspecialchars_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php)

Comment: Não deu, continuo aparecendo tags em html ;s

Comment: coloque uma imagem do resultado na sua questão, por favor?

Comment: Postei @HarryPotter

Comment: @PauloPimentel use só htmlspecialchars_decode

Comment: deu o segundo 
<?php echo(htmlspecialchars_decode($usr['descricaodoevento']));?>
Obrigado pela ajuda *-*